# How to format TestNG reports in second not millisecond ?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng, test-report

I want convert the milliseconds to seconds in TestNg emailable report.
Please help?

[image: testng emailable report]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to extend the report.  See here for an example:

http://djangofan.github.io/testng-custom-report-example/

[image]